# Redirect to anchor point with php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, anchor

So I have a question about a redirect to an anchor point. In my case I have a anchor with the id= `product` I have for the redirect this code:

```
<?php Header(
    "Location: http://localhost/#product",
    true,
    301
);
?>
```

The problem is that I will redirect to `http://localhost/#product/` and this is not my anchor point. I could rename it to `product/` but I don't like this solution. It would be nice if anyone have a better solution.

Or maybe I can redirect it with the htaccess. If anyone have an example for this. The site which I want to redirect is `http://localhost/home/product/`

Comment: _“The problem is that I will redirect to http://localhost/#product/”_ - can’t reproduce. I am guessing you must have something else working in some place or other, that affects this. Start investigating by checking what the actual content of the Location header in the response is, in your browser dev tools, network panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem was that there was a setting in wordpress for permealinks with the slash at the end.